# How to start a Parse Server with Express using npm package parse-server?

Tags: node.js, parse-server

I installed and managed to run properly the open source version of the Parse Server **with Express** using the example server that they have on Github (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example).

This is what I did:

1. I cloned the parse-server-example repo.
2. Edited the file `index.js` based on my needs.
3. Then I ran `npm install` and `npm start`.

Now I want to achieve the same thing using the package **parse-server** available on npm, but based on the instructions that I found in the package page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server) I couldn't figure out how to run it **with Express**. I managed to run it only without Express.

In other words, I don't want to clone the parse-server-example every time I need to use Parse. I want to start my server using only the `parse-server` command line tool and the `index.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

`npm start`. If you have nodemon installed you can use that too.

Answer (score -1):

You can start it with

```
node index.js
```

Also in dev environments you can use forever , it will give automatic restarting of node server when any file changes or any crash occurs, just like it was with parse cli .

```
forever start index.js
```

Also i would recommend using `cluster module` to get better performance out of parse-server

Comment: But you're not using the `parse-server` command line as I specified in my original question. I know how to do that using `node`, but when I use `parse-server` it doesn't use Express.